# NLME GLS Model Formula

Tags: r, nlme

I have a script which, given a response variable and predictors, generates all possible model combinations. I have saved all combinations for my data in a list (length 155). I have written a loop which, on each iteration, uses the next formula on the list:

```
prico.models.exp <- foreach(z = 1:length(model.formulae), .packages=c("nlme")) %dopar% {
      gls(as.formula(model.formulae[z]),data=prico,subset=Freq>50,correlation=corExp(form=~x+y, nugget=T),na.action=na.omit,method="ML",control=xx)
}
```

When I view the model summaries of each output, the model is listed as `as.formula(model.formulae[z])` and not the actual formula (in my example, model 1 would be `richness ~ lai`). The correct response and predictors have been used as the model coefficients are correct. For example:

```
Generalized least squares fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: as.formula(model.formulae[z]) 
  Data: prico 
  Subset: Freq > 50 
  Log-likelihood: 66.02798

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         lai 
3.149229862 0.007314029 

Correlation Structure: Exponential spatial correlation
 Formula: ~x + y 
 Parameter estimate(s):
       range       nugget 
3.634669e+04 2.123560e-11 
Degrees of freedom: 88 total; 86 residual
Residual standard error: 0.2020574
```

It is important that the model is transferred from the list to the model summary as other functions (e.g. model.avg in MuMIn) requires a formula in the model summary to work. Is it possible to use a loop and keep the formula in the model summary?